# accessing properties file in cloudbees environment

Tags: properties, resources, filepath, cloudbees

Here is a reduction of my problem:

I have the following file:  src/main/resources/configs/config.properties
The file has one property: uselive = true

I want to access this file from a java web app hosted on Cloudbees platform and read its content.

What is the access path that I should use in order to read this file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't rely on filesystem on RUN@Cloud. Filesystem is not persistent neither distributed, so as your application is (re)deployed it will get a fresh new node with empty filesystem, or if you scale-out on the cluster all nodes won't see consistent files.

We provide http://wiki.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/Configuration+Parameters to handle application configuration. You also can put system properties configuration in http://wiki.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/CloudBeesWebXml as well if you prefer this option

Comment: Thanks Nicolas, however, this file is part of the distribution WAR so it will be deployed along with the code.    In the WAR file it will be found in /app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/classes/configs/, I just don't know what path it will assume when deployed in cloudbees.

Comment: if in `WEB-INF/classes` then you can use `getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/configs/config.properties")` that also works if the file is inside a `.jar` in `WEB-INF/lib/*.jar` otherwise you need to access via the `ServletContext` to get a file otherwise within the `.war`

Answer (score 2):

Generally you will access resources deployed in your WEB-INF folder using your class-loader:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String

So something like the following will give you a stream:

```
getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("configs/config.properties");
```